# How to eliminate the parent view's background color effect in a child view? react native

Tags: react-native

How to eliminate the parent's background color effect in child. Below I have comment.

below I have attact image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmsV5.jpg)

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B7LcuZLOPxbW2ovYd6yuIF7xjeZKYycI/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmsV5.jpg)

```
<RNCamera
            ref={cameraRef}
            style={{ flex: 1, }}
            type={RNCamera.Constants.Type[cameraType]}
            autoFocus={'on'}
            barCodeTypes={[RNCamera.Constants.BarCodeType.qr]}
            captureAudio={false}
            zoom={cameraZoom}
            flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode[flashMode]}
            onBarCodeRead={onBarCodeRead}
        >
            {() => {
                return (
                    <View style={styles.container}> //here I specify the color 
                        


//doesn't want the background color effect which I have specify in parent view "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" here, I want bright and clean the LottieView.

                        <LottieView style={{  
                         height: hp('40%')
                        }}
                            source={require('../Asserts/Animations/scanner2.json')}
                            autoPlay
                            loop
                        />
</RNCamera>



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'  //specify color here

    }
});
```

Comment: hey can you share an expo snack? will chcek there

Comment: what part do you want bright? cant get in that image

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give you child component the background. If you want it to be transparent you can try with `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` or `backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, alpha)'.`

Comment: Actually, on the back of both parent and child views there is a Camera. kindly preview the image as I mentioned. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B7LcuZLOPxbW2ovYd6yuIF7xjeZKYycI/view?usp=sharing